# Implementing baresip NDK library causes lack of *.so file

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, sip, baresip

I want to implement [baresip](https://github.com/alfredh/baresip) lib into my Android project using NDK.

I've found up-to-date "bare bones" demo-project in [HERE](https://github.com/juha-h/baresip-studio). As in readme I've created some native libs from another repo and placed in "distribution" folder. Project is compiling, installing, working fine. Comparing to Android native sip implementation this lib is just awesome, use it, forget about `permission.USE_SIP`, its rubish.

Now I want to import baresip into my project, but without Java/Kotlin files, planning to build own. So my steps:

1. Added `externalNativeBuild` entries to build.gradle
2. Copied `cpp` and `distribution` folders to proper places in my structure
3. Invalidate cache and restart

And got exception:

> Build command failed.
>
> Error while executing process C:\Android\sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build C:\Android\projects\MyApplication\app.cxx\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a --target baresip}
>
> [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/baresip.dir/baresip.c.o
>
> [2/2] Linking C shared library C:\Android\projects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a\libbaresip.so
>
> FAILED: cmd.exe /C "..."

next some duplicated lines like:

> src/video.c:331: error: undefined reference to 'atof'
>
> src/main/main.c:944: error: undefined reference to 'signal'
>
> src/main/main.c:775: error: undefined reference to '__FD_ISSET_chk'
>
> src/main/main.c:690: error: undefined reference to '__FD_SET_chk'
>
> C:/Android/projects/MyApplication/app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/openssl/lib/armeabi-v7a/libcrypto.a(armcap.o):armcap.c:function OPENSSL_cpuid_setup: error: undefined reference to 'sigfillset'

and ends with

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

note `app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/` files path, as declared in `CMakeLists`:

```
set(distribution_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../distribution)
```

For me it looks like not-visible files for compiler, but when I add/remove some/any `../` error changes to clearly suggesting wrong path. besides same path and hierarchy is in sample project

I've tried to strip out `baresip.c` file, but its crashing with just logging `OnLoad` call...

```
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <re.h>
#include <baresip.h>

#define LOGD(...) \
    if (log_level_get() < LEVEL_INFO) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Baresip Lib", __VA_ARGS__))


JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved) {
    LOGD("at JNI_OnLoad\n");
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
```

crash still occurs, but when I comment out `if (log_level_get() < LEVEL_INFO)` call my project is building and install just fine... `log_level_get()` comes from `baresip.h`, which is `#include`d, `libbaresip.a` files (per abi) present, so why is `libbaresip.so` missing, why it isn't generating? what lines are present in sample project which makes it to build and work?

(yep, I'm pretty weak in native, lost some support from colleagues due to coronavirus...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turns out it was a bit hidden, but nothing tough... target/compile SDK version should be at least 21 for this lib, I had 19, thats why ndk wasn't compiling properly...